# Querying to construct XML in TSQL without a source table, only variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using a SELECT statement in MS SQL 2005 TSQL, and no source table, just variables as listed below...

```
@FirstName varchar(20)
@LastName varchar(20)
@ZipCode varchar(5)
```

...what syntax will build XML resembling the following?

```
<XMLDATA><REC FirstName="JOHN" LastName="SMITH" ZipCode="98052" /></XMLDATA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(20) 
SET @FirstName = 'JOHN'

DECLARE @LastName varchar(20)
SET @LastName = 'SMITH'

DECLARE @ZipCode varchar(5)
SET @ZipCode = '98052'

SELECT
 @FirstName AS '@FirstName',
 @LastName AS '@LastName',
 @ZipCode AS '@ZipCode'
FOR 
    XML PATH('REC'), ROOT('XMLDATA')
```

The `FOR XML PATH('REC')` defines the XML tag and the `AS '@FirstName'` specifies you want this value to be an attribute on that XML tag. The `ROOT('XMLDATA')` wraps the whole thing into yet another XML Tag on the outside.